# What am I doing wrong with Rails has_many and belongs_to association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm creating an app to log when files are moved to an archive drive, where they came from and were moved to and what user moved them.

This is my Archive model:

```
class Archive < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :archive_date, :start_dir, :end_dir, :user_id

  #added by chris

  belongs_to :user
end
```

This is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # new columns need to be added here to be writable through mass assignment
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :user_id

  attr_accessor :password
  before_save :prepare_password
  before_save :assign_user_id

  #added by chris
  has_many :archives

  def assign_user_id
    self.user_id = User.maximum('user_id') + 1
  end

end
```

This is my view:

```
<table id="archive_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Archive Date</th>
    <th>Source Directory</th>
    <th>Archive Directory</th>
    <th>Archived By ID</th>
    <th>Archived By Name</th>
  </tr>
  <% for archive in @archives %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= archive.archive_date %></td>
      <td><%= archive.start_dir %></td>
      <td><%= archive.end_dir %></td>
      <td><%= archive.user_id %></td>
      <td><%= archive.username %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Show", archive %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_archive_path(archive) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Destroy", archive, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>

<p><%= link_to "New Archive", new_archive_path %></p>
```

When I start up my local rails server via `rails s` Try to load the page. This is what I get:

```
NoMethodError in Archives#index

Showing c:/appname/app/views/archives/index.html.erb where line #21 raised:

undefined method `username' for #<Archive:0x203d750>

Extracted source (around line #21):

18:       <td><%= archive.start_dir %></td>
19:       <td><%= archive.end_dir %></td>
20:       <td><%= archive.user_id %></td>
21:       <td><%= archive.username %></td>
22:       <td><%= link_to "Show", archive %></td>
23:       <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_archive_path(archive) %></td>
24:       <td><%= link_to "Destroy", archive, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>

Rails.root: c:
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/views/archives/index.html.erb:21:in `block in _app_views_archives_index_html_erb__238412483_16592988'
app/views/archives/index.html.erb:15:in `each'
app/views/archives/index.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_archives_index_html_erb__238412483_16592988'
```

Assuming the archive record is correctly saved with the users User_ID how do i get my view to display the name of the user via the has_many belongs_to association?

Thank You for looking at my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Archives have users, users have usernames--I think you're just up one level to "high"; use:

```
  <%= archive.user.username %>
```